# split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes according to distribution of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, distribution

Changed question and picture (as I said before... its complicated :)

[image: I added a "picture" to describe what I want.]

I have a pandas dataframe 'df' that has a column 'score' (floating point values) with a distribution (lets say a normal distribution). I additionally have an integer 'splits' (lets say 3) and a floating point number 'gap' (lets say 0.5).

I would like to have two dataframes 'gaps_df' and 'rest_df'. 'gaps_df' should consist of all entries from df that are marked orange in the picture (every two red lines have distance 'gap'). 'rest_df' consists of all entries which are marked green.

Here is the tricky part: The green areas have to be of equal size!

To be clear:

- the GREEN areas have to be of equal amount of entries!
- the ORANGE areas have to consist of entries within the gap-range (amount doesn't matter) between the green areas

So far I have the following:

```
df.sort('score')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
split_markers = []
for marker_index in range(1, classes):
    split_markers.append(marker_index * df.size/classes)
```

But the last two lines are wrong since they split the WHOLE AREA into equal amount of entries. With a normal distribution, I could just move the markers 0.5*gap to the left and to the right. But in fact: I do NOT have a normal distribution (this was just to quickly create a picture with equal green areas).

It gets freaking me out. I really do appreciate every help you can give! Maybe there is a way easier solution...

Comment: Do you have any sample dataset?

Comment: Checkout the qcut function it allows you to create equal sized buckets automatically:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html

Comment: no sorry I cannot share the data. But it can be random floating point numbers like: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500), columns=['score'])

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Thank you: But as far as I see it, this doesn't help me, because I need the gaps (depending on the distribution scale) in-between. These gaps can be of different entry amount (and will be if its not a normal distribution) but need to have equal length on the distribution scale.

Comment: Ah now I understand the problem. But tbh. this doesn't sound like pandas related question, it's more likely a mathematical problem. Because all you need to do is find x0 and x1 which describe the center of you gaps. Once you have them it's not hard to create the dataframes. `df_gap = df[((df.score > x0 - gap/2) & (df.score < x0 + gap/2)) | ((df.score > x1 - gap/2) & (df.score < x1 + gap/2))]`
`df_tmp = df[~df.score.isin(df_gap.score)]`

Then you can create the df_rest using the qcut function.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis yep, you are right. Its actually a math problem. And afterwards a 'how do I apply the solution to pandas problem' which you solved above :) Thank you. Do you have any idea where I could post the math question regarding the center of the gaps?

Comment: You could try to post it here:
https://mathoverflow.net/ ;)

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Thanks a lot for your help! If anyone here wants to solve the math problem, its posted here :) [link] (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270028/split-distribution-into-areas-with-equal-amount-of-entries-and-gaps-with-fixed-w)